# Entity framework with SAP HANA

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, hana

I have built a WPF application with Entity Framework on SQL Server as database. I am trying to migrate the same application with SAP HANA as database. Following the same approach, I have created the tables in HANA db and now trying to add an entity model in the solution by following this SAP help:
[SAP HANA Client Interface Programming Reference](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/1.0.12/en-US/657b277c66c945ff8fdd66e7a12e3c83.html)

While adding the entity model, after selection of data source and option to include sensitive data in connection string, the wizard disappears. 
**Please help if anyone has used entity framework with HANA.**

I have used all the 32 bit versions of HANA client available on SAP market place without any success.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Entity Framework by using the adding a reference to the `dll` provided in the installation directory.

The name of the dll is `System.Data.CData.SAPHANA.Entities.EF6.dll` and you should have installed EntityFramework using `Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.3.0`  command. Please don't forget to use the version flag because it didn't work with another version and I didn't try to know why.

Now the remaining thing is the connection string

```
<add name="HANA_DbContext" connectionString="Offline=False;User=system;
Password=Secret_Pass;Server=hana.office.internal.com;
Database=company_erp;" providerName="System.Data.CData.SAPHANA" />
```

Here now, everything should work correctly as if it works MySQL, SQL Server or another ORM